# change web3-js version used in javascript

Tags: web3js, testrpc

In the node command, the web3 version used is 1.0.0 and the function like:

```
web3.eth.accounts.create();
```

is working properly but in my webpage running on ganache-cli(testrpc) the same command is not working and its reporting error

```
web3.eth.accounts.create is not a function
```

how can I change the web3js version of ganache-cli/ the version used by my javascript file?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the correct web3 js file bundled in your webpage.